# Whats the best way to handle changing variables in different place values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m trying to make a script that will generate every possible combination of letters and integers, given the user provides a length. Then writes this data to a txt file.

[image]

how should I go about handling each place value character?

Side note, I’d like it to go in this format:
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
etc

side note 2, I'd prefer solutions or suggestions that don't involve modules but won't refuse them.

Comment: So if the user gave 5 as input will it write the combinations that start from length 1 and up to length 5 or only write the ones that are length 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python -> combinations of numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719850/python-combinations-of-numbers-and-letters)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show what you have done so far the solve _your_ problem? SO isn't a tutorial replacement. You need to show some effort and then pose questions related to _your_ code. Also, providing an MRE helps users to create answers ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, [r])`, where iterable is your array and `r` is the length of the result string.
**For example:**

```
combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2) --> AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD
```