# Generate random ASCII strings until first N characters of it's hash matches specific string

Tags: python, linux, string, hash, cryptography

So I'm trying to create a program in Python that generates a bunch of random ASCII strings that gets hashed with the specified id number "1234". The goal is to try to find a valid string where the first 6 letters of its hash starts with "a0eebb" and the 7th and 8th characters are equal to "34", the last 2 characters of the id string.

The problem is my program has been running for over 13 hours, and there hasn't been a match. I'm wondering if something might be wrong with the logic of my program?

I was also wondering if there might be a way to speed up the process - I came across using multiple threads, but wasn't sure how I would incorporate that into my program. So far, I've just been running the program on multiple command line terminals that are open.

My program just generates strings of 10 characters by default, but the length could be anything. I also found a suggestion to use itertools.product to generate the ascii strings? Wasn't sure how that worked/if it would be any different than what I am doing now.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import string
import hashlib
import random

id = "1234"
random_string = ""
count = 0

while True:   
    random_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10))
    random_string_with_salt = random_string + id    
    random_string_hash = hashlib.sha256(random_string_with_salt.encode()).hexdigest()
    print("Random string generated: " + random_string)  
    count = count + 1        
    print("Count: " + str(count))     
    if ((random_string_hash[0:6] == "a0eebb") and (random_string_hash[6:8] == id[-2:])): 
        valid_string = random_string
        print("Random string generated: " + valid_string)
        print("Random string hash:  " + random_string_hash)
        print("Count: " + str(count))
        break
```

Comment: You have vastly understimated the time this will take.

Comment: You are expecting to match 4 bytes on output, that shouldn't take too long. You should consider optimizations, such as calling `digest()` and not `hexdigest()` and matching against a bytes object, not a string. Don't bother generating a random string, just use simple methods to generate the next string, and it doesn't need to be more than 5 bytes.

Comment: Hello @PresidentJamesK.Polk, by "Don't bother generating a random string, just use simple methods to generate the next string", do you mean doing something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719850/combinations-of-numbers-and-letters As in instead of generating random combinations, I try to go through all possible combinations of ASCII characters, add 1 to the length, and repeat the process?

Comment: I meant using something like `itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with my comments here is an example of what I was trying to explain.

```py
import hashlib
import itertools
import time

# match_target = bytes.fromhex('a0eebb34')
match_target = bytes.fromhex('a0eebb')

alphabet = ''.join(map(chr, range(33, 127))).encode('ascii')


def find_hash_input(target: bytes) -> tuple[str, int]:
    target_len = len(target)
    iteration_count = 0
    for input_tuple in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=6):
        input_bytes = bytearray(input_tuple)
        iteration_count += 1
        if hashlib.sha256(input_bytes).digest()[:target_len] == target:
            return input_bytes.decode('ascii'), iteration_count


def tests():
    start = time.process_time()
    input_str, count = find_hash_input(match_target)
    elapsed = time.process_time() - start
    print(f'found {input_str} in {elapsed} seconds')
    # check
    if hashlib.sha256(input_str.encode('ascii')).digest()[: len(match_target)] != match_target:
        print('failure')
    else:
        print(f'success after {count} iterations')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests()
```

<strike>This takes about 8 seconds on my machine to find the first 3 bytes of the match. Therefore, to find all four I would expect it take about 256 times as long. In other words, less than an hour.</strike>

Actually, more careful measurement shows that it *should* take around 23 seconds to find the 3 byte match, thus the expected time to find a 4 byte match would be around 1.7 hours on my machine.

The expression [`itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=6)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) may need some explanation. The expected number of iterations to success is 2<sup>number of bits to be matched</sup> = 2<sup>32</sup> in this case. However, there is variance in this statistic, it might take fewer iterations or it might take more. The number of distinct values generated by `itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=k)` is len(alphabet)<sup>k</sup>. Our alphabet has 94 characters. With `repeat=5` we would be able to generate about 2<sup>32.8</sup> inputs. That's more than we expect to need but with the variance it's possible we'll run out of inputs before we find a match. With `repeat=6` we can generate 2<sup>39.3</sup> inputs, more than enough. I really should have a more general calculation for the repeat count. Perhaps I'll add it in a later edit.